# centering of content (css)

Tags: html, css

I just can't seem to figure this out - I'm trying to get the top section (class=top) to center regardless of screen resolution.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

EDIT: hahah sorry! I completly forgot the link!! :)

- linked removed

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: try `margin: 0px auto` on a block element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It slightly depends on your site structure, but if you mean horizontal centering setting a horizontal `margin` of `auto` should work.

```
margin: auto; /* will set vertical margin as well, but this won't have an effect */
```

If you are talking about vertical centering it's a lot more complicated:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

**Edit:** *you added a link to your site*

In your specific case, setting the `margin` of `.top` to `auto` won't cut it because of two reasons:

1. `.top` has a `width` of `100%` because it's a block-level element.
2. `.top` needs this width of `100%` because of the background color

To fix this, add another `div` within `.top`, give this `div` a fixed width that is wide enough to contain all the content (it seems you need `1124px`) and give this `div` the `margin:auto`.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks :) - works great although I now have other positioning issues :)

Comment: Hey, if my answer fixed your problem you should vote it up and accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the css margin attribute..

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link your website but if you're trying to center a div inside its parent horazontally you can use this:

```
.top{ margin:0 auto; }

<div class="top">content</div>
```